# Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol A referenced in function ARoutine

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86-64, masm, masm64

I've been grappling with this for about a day now and have yet to find the solution. I'm trying to access a global variable, declared in main.cpp, from an Testing.asm file with both files in the same project using Visual Studio 2019. But I'm getting the following linking error:

```
    Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol referenced in function TestRoutine
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
        extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) A; //global variable
        .....
```

```
    ########################### Testing.asm #####################
    EXTERN A:QWORD

    .data    

    .code

    main PROC

    main ENDP

    TestRoutine PROC PUBLIC

    MOV EAX, DWORD PTR A 
    RET

    TestRoutine ENDP

    END
```

Comment: Using `extern "C"` like that does not define the variable so it does not exist. Try `extern "C" { int A; }` instead. You might also need to use `_A` in your assembly file in case a leading underscore is automatically prepended. Use `dumpbin` to verify symbol name.

Comment: Note that name mangling is not applied to variables so you do not even need the `extern "C"`.

Comment: @Jester thank you it (extern "C" { int A; }) worked! If you can post your comment as a answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar bug in my program.
Use `extern "C" {int A;}` to solve it.
BTW you declared `A` as an int which is a double word (32 bits).
And later you declared `EXTERN A:QWORD` which is 64 bits.
At the end, you used `MOV EAX, DWORD PTR A`.
A more straightforward approach is to declare `A` as a `DWORD` and remove the `DWORD PTR` type casting.

Comment: You don't need `extern "C"` at all, just `int A;` compiles to the same asm.  (Because variable names don't get name-mangled at least in mainstream compilers; only function names do to support overloading.)  But yes, you need the C to actually define it, not just have an `extern int A;` reference, unless you want the asm to actually define it with `dd 0` or something.  One or the other of the asm and C++ should use `extern` on the variable itself to declare it without reserving space for it.